# How to stored a SUM result in a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

```
    Medical_Appointment

        ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        Day DATE NOT NULL,
        Start_Time TIME NOT NULL,
        Patient_ID INT NOT NULL,
        Service_ID INT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID)
```

And

```
Service

        ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        Duration VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(ID)
```

I want to get the end time of every appointment, and for that I have the next query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(m.Day, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `Appointment day:`, 
TIME_FORMAT(m.Start_Time, '%H:%i') AS `Appointment start time:`,
ADDTIME(m.Start_Time, TIME_FORMAT(s.Duration, '%H:%i')) AS `Appointment end time:`
FROM Medical_Appointment m 
JOIN Service s 
ON m.Service_ID = s.ID
WHERE m.Day = '2017-03-14'
ORDER BY m.Start_Time;
```

This works for me, but it is just a temporary view, I want to stored the result in a column for the Medical_Appointment table because I want to use that value in a Java application and just take it from the database. This is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Alter your table to add the new column.

After that, just insert the result of your select

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MySQL Table View for that:

```
CREATE VIEW appointment_info
AS SELECT DATE_FORMAT(m.Day, '%d-%m-%Y') AS `day`, 
   TIME_FORMAT(m.Start_Time, '%H:%i') AS `start`,
   ADDTIME(m.Start_Time, TIME_FORMAT(s.Duration, '%H:%i')) AS `end`
   FROM Medical_Appointment m 
   JOIN Service s 
   ON m.Service_ID = s.ID;
```

You could then query the view 'appointment_info' like a usual table e.g.:

```
SELECT `day` AS `Appointment day:`, `start` AS `Appointment start time:`, `end` AS `Appointment end time:`
FROM appointment_info
WHERE day = '2017-03-14'
ORDER BY `start`;
```

Of course you could also use `Appointment day:`, `Appointment start time:` and `Appointment end time:` directly as column names in your table view.

Answer (score 0):

you would have had **end time** when updating duration; so you should just also include end time as a field.

P.S. i was unable to comment so writing it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check if database 'trigger' can be useful here. Triggers should do the purpose.